# Show ProgressDialog for Radio streaming Service?

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I have made an app for radio streaming here is the code:

```
     public class streamService extends Service {

public static MediaPlayer stream;
public static String url;
public static int serviceAvailable;
private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public static PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
public static Boolean bgPlay = false;
TelephonyManager tm;

ProgressDialog pDialog;

public static String Tag="";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    pDialog=new ProgressDialog(RadioList.con);
    pDialog.setTitle("Please wait!!");
    pDialog.setMessage("Connecting");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    // Restore preferences

    Tag=RadioList.Tag;
    //RadioStationThree.pDialog.show();
    stream = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        stream.setDataSource(RadioList.URL);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
    stream.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    stream.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer stream) {


        /*  tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            makeNotification();
        */  // Set the Wake Lock - CPU on, keyboard and screen off
            /*PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK,
                    getString(R.string.app_name));
            wl.acquire();*/
            serviceAvailable = 1;

            System.out.println("HERE CANCEL");
            pDialog.cancel();

            stream.start();


        }
    });
    try {
        stream.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // kill the stream
    serviceAvailable = 0;
    stream.stop();
    stream.release();
    stream = null;
    // kill the status notification
}
```

This service is started at click of a button in activity But as I click on the button the app stops working for a while and then continue normal(Sometimes ANR is also shown). I also used ProgressDialog but it also stop spinning and ANR is shown .What could be the possible solution for this? Please Help?

Comment: dont do the heavy task directly in main thread. use separate thread

Comment: i am new to threads can u help me with some code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "StinePike" It was simple using the code in new thread it worked all fine!